# Finding IP Address of Client and Server in Socket Programming

Tags: c, sockets

I have started practicing Socket Programming and I have written client and server program in C and they are communicating fine. However, I wish to find the IP address of Client as well as Server and print it in both the programs.

Here is my client code ...

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 


struct node 
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[10];
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int socketFD,port;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress, clientAddress;
    struct hostent *server;
    if (argc < 3) 
    {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    port = atoi(argv[2]);
    socketFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socketFD < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(port);

    clientAddress.sin_family=AF_INET;
    clientAddress.sin_port=htons(port);
    clientAddress.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (connect(socketFD,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress,sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) error("ERROR connecting");

    struct node temp;
    temp.a=21;
    temp.b=32;
    temp.c[0]='T';
    temp.c[1]='E';
    temp.c[2]='M';
    temp.c[3]='P';
    sendto(socketFD, (void *) &temp, sizeof(temp), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    printf("%s - %s", inet_ntoa(serverAddress.sin_addr), inet_ntoa(clientAddress.sin_addr));


    return 0;
}
```

and here is my server code

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 


struct node 
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[10];
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int socketFD,port,clientFD,clientLen;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress, clientAddress;
    if((socketFD=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
    {
        printf("Unable to create socket\n");
        return 1;
    }
    bzero((char*)&serverAddress,sizeof(serverAddress));
    port=atoi(argv[1]);
    serverAddress.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port=htons(port);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if((bind(socketFD,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)))<0)
    {
        printf("Error on binding\n");
        return 1;   
    }
    listen(socketFD,5);
    clientLen=sizeof(clientAddress);
    clientFD=accept(socketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &clientLen);

    struct node temp;
    recvfrom(clientFD, (void *)&temp, sizeof(temp), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress,  &clientLen); 

    printf("%d-%d-%s\n", temp.a, temp.b, temp.c);
    printf("%s - %s", inet_ntoa(serverAddress.sin_addr), inet_ntoa(clientAddress.sin_addr));
     close(clientFD);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am facing with server program is that in the output it is printing the value given to struct variable followed by some unknown characters and the IP address of client and server is printed as 0.0.0.0 for both..

What is the problem and How to solve it??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger, first client side, then server side ? And did you try to control return values of IO functions ? IMHO you should start that way to see exactly where the problem is.

Comment: You don't null-terminate `temp.c`, so printing it with `printf` invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

See the docs:

> The  inet_ntoa()  function  converts the Internet host address in, given in network byte order, to a
>          string in IPv4 dotted-decimal notation.  The string is returned in a  statically  allocated  buffer,
>          **which subsequent calls will overwrite**.

Answer (score 0):

Different problems in your code.

As noticed by Colonel Thirty Two, you do not set temp to 0 before loading it, so you could have garbage in c[4] to c[9]

You use 2 time inet_ntoa in same printf, what ends in printing both the second address as explained by David Schwartz

You do not test all the functions

You use same port in client for bind and connect. If you are trying to communicate on localhost, it cannot work since port is already bound for server. Unless you have a good reason to do so, you'd better bind client port to 0 meaning *choose any appropriate free port*.

Once that's fixed, your programs correctly exchange data and show both addresses.